# SCSS add alpha to colour if none given?

Tags: sass

With scss I can easily add an alpha to a colour with `rgba($colour, 0.5)`, however, this overrides the alpha channel if `$colour` already has one. Is there a way to only add the alpha channel when none is given?

For example:

```scss
with-default-alpha(rgb(0,0,0), 0.5) // would add an alpha channel and return rgba(0,0,0, 0.5) 
with-default-alpha(rgba(0,0,0,1), 0.5) // would do nothing and return rgba(0,0,0, 1)
```

That way I could make a function that takes a colour, and if an alpha channel is given it'll use that, otherwise it'll add a default.